# Запятые. Верно ли?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сложное-предложение

> Здравствуйте. Скажите, пожалуйста, после проведения вступительных
> испытаний, для зачисления абитуриента в вуз необходимо его присутствие
> в вузе, или можно будет подать заявление о согласии на зачисление
> онлайн?

Не могу разобраться со знаками препинания в тексте выше. Подскажите, верно ли? Как расставлять запятые в таких сложных предложениях?

Answer (score 1):

> Скажите, пожалуйста, после проведения вступительных испытаний, для
> зачисления абитуриента в вуз необходимо его присутствие в вузе, или
> можно будет подать заявление о согласии на зачисление онлайн?

Третья и четвёртая запятые  лишние, а после *пожалуйста* лучше поставить двоеточие.

О том, когда запятая перед *или* нужна, а когда не нужна: https://pishugramotno.ru/punktuacia/nuzhna-li-zapyataya-pered-ili

С третьей запятой проще: она была бы нужна для разделения однородных членов предложения, а в данном случае они не однородны: *после проведения вступительных испытаний* — обстоятельство времени, а *для зачисления абитуриента в вуз* — указание цели.

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае (в деловом стиле) не все запятые нужны:

*Скажите, пожалуйста, **после проведения вступительных испытаний для зачисления абитуриента в вуз** необходимо его присутствие в вузе **или** можно будет подать заявление о согласии на зачисление онлайн?*

В начале предложения **два неоднородных обстоятельства,** которые являются общим  элементом в сложносочиненном предложении, где простые предложения связаны одиночным союзом ИЛИ. Также общим элементом является **вопросительная интонация**.

Розенталь, пункты 2(1) и 3 http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133